# Why does declaring a variable after an executable statement not work with MS C compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is a part in my code that causing me a lot of trouble:

```
struct _RandomPermutationIterator
{
    size_t n, *arrp;
    size_t i;
};

typedef struct _RandomPermutationIterator RandomPermutationIterator;

RandomPermutationIterator *RandomPermutationIterator_alloc(size_t n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    RandomPermutationIterator *its = (RandomPermutationIterator*)malloc(sizeof(RandomPermutationIterator));
    …
}
```

The errors I received:

- `error C2275: 'RandomPermutationIterator' : illegal use of this type as an expression.`
- `error C2065: 'its' : undeclared identifier.`

Can someone explain them to me and tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: can you write a better title? you need to move the line with `its` over the call of srand()

Comment: Which line is the error on? What happens if you just replace `RandomPermutationIterator` with `struct _RandomPermutationIterator` everywhere?

Comment: A program usually should not call `srand(time(NULL))` more than once.

Comment: You should probably enter the 21st century, and either put your compiler in C99 mode, or get a better compiler if yours doesn't have such a mode.

Answer (score 6):

Judging from the error message numbers, you're using MS Visual C++ as a C compiler.  It supports C89, not C99 or C11.  You cannot define variables after an executable statement (unlike in C++ or C99 or later).

In your outline function, the `srand()` call is an executable statement; you can't declare variables after that.

The 'obvious' fix is to move the call to `srand()` after the variable definition.  However, the correct fix is to remove the `srand(time(NULL));` call — you should (normally) only call `srand()` once in a given process anyway.

Incidentally, identifiers starting with an underscore and either another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation.  That means you should *not* use them yourself.  Simply remove the leading underscore; the typedef name and the tag name are in separate namespaces, so you can perfectly well use:

```
typedef struct RandomPermutationIterator RandomPermutationIterator;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a C file, you HAVE to initialize variables in the beginning of a block. I.e., the declaration has to be immediately after the opening braces '{' . Either switch to c++ and compile it as a c++ program and rename your file as .cpp or .cc OR just simply move the declaration of *its above your srand().

Comment: This is accurate while using C compilers that do not support C99 or C11 (such as the Microsoft compiler).